# How to create files in %appdata% with c++

Tags: c++, windows, file, appdata

I need help creating a Folder in AppData.
Lets say I want to create a Folder in %appdata% called "MyFolder", which has the text file test.txt
I tried to use `<fstream>` and do this;

```
ofstream file("%appdata%\MyFolder\test.txt");
```

but it didn't work..

Comment: Define "didn't work."

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things like %appdata%  are OS specific, and Standard C++ has no direct means of dealing with them. You will have to write code to parse the file path, and extract values like %appdata% from the environment, or alternatively use non-standard functions to open the file, should such exist.

P.S. It also wouldn't work because "\" escapes the quotes, do "\\" instead.