# c++ Fstream string combination error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a function that writes a .ps1 script. I'm learning fstream functions and methods and I ran in to some troubles. I can't figure a way to make Fstream create the file at the given path (path1) and add in the same time a given name for the file and the extension.

```
void write(string s, string name) {

    ostringstream fille;
    fille << "$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient\n" << s;
    string fil = fille.str();
    ostringstream pat;
    pat << path1 << "/" << ".ps1";
    string path = pat.str();
    fstream file(path);
    if (file.open()) {
        file << fil;
        file.close();
    }
}
```

I get the following error message (on the `if` line) during compilation:

> no instance of overloaded function "`std::basic_fstream<_Elem, _Traits>::open` [with _Elem=`char`, _Traits=`std::char_traits<char>`]" matches the argument list
>
> C2661 '`std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>‌​::open`': no overloaded function takes 0 arguments

Comment: What is `path1`?

Comment: Path 1 is a string with the path : "C:/Folder/"

Comment: you need to supply the mode in which you want to open. default is read only if iam not mistaken. alternatively you can use ofstream, which will default to writing

Comment: I will try that out !

Comment: What is the problem? "I can't" isn't a question valid for SO. Did you get an error message? Did something not happen that you expected to happen? Did something happen that you did not expect to happen? If you want us to solve your problem for you, you are going to have to tell us what it is.

Comment: @jonas_toth: No, [the default is read/write](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream).

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active)  no instance of overloaded function "std::basic_fstream<_Elem, _Traits>::open [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]" matches the argument list (ERROR at if statement)

And other one : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2661 'std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::open': no overloaded function takes 0 arguments

Comment: Put the error message clearly _in the question_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What do you think is causing the errors ?

Comment: @AlexM.: Put the error message clearly _in the question_.

Comment: Change `if (file.open())` to just `if (file)`. Change `fstream` to `ofstream`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Can I ask you one more thing ? Why, if I use in the path %Appdata%/AppFolder/ It can't write to that ?

Comment: @AlexM.: Because that is not a path. You should really perform some research. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5920853/560648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't use `name` parameter.
Second you don't define path1 variable.
And you do not need to call `fstream::open` method if you use fstream's **initialization constructor**.

```
    void write( const std::string & s, const std::string & name )
    {
         std::string fil("$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient\n");
         fil += s;

         std::ostringstream path;
         path << "C:/Folder/" << name << ".ps1";

         std::ofstream file( path.str() );
         if ( file.is_open() ) {
             file << fil;
             file.close();
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for bringing me to light !

Comment: @JustRufs If I were to use a path shorcut like : %Appdata%/Folder would it work ? For me, at the moment it doesn't.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034847/how-to-create-files-in-appdata-with-c

Comment: So I will have to see how to I store a cmd command in a variable, right ?

Comment: Try this: 
`#include <stdlib.h>
std::string appdata( getenv("APPDATA") );` Currently I don't have PC/Laptop with windows system, so could not try.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (file.open()) {
```

Look at [a reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream): as the error message states, there isn't a member function of `fstream` called `open` that takes no arguments.

This is probably a typo for:

```
if (file.is_open()) {
```

Comment: Omg.. Dude, I'm so sorry for wasting your time. I can't belive I'm so dumb... Thank you.. And sorry one more time...